# I can't convert the pytorch maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn model to the scripted module

Tags: torch, torchvision, libtorch

I just want to convert standatd torchvision model to libtorch format

```
loaded_model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False)

# loaded_model.cpu()
loaded_model.eval()
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 256, 256)
scripted_model = torch.jit.script(loaded_model)
out = loaded_model(example)
scripted_model.save('../models/vanila_rcnn.pt')
out[0]["boxes"]
```

It works and predicts boxes etc: tensor([], size=(0, 4), grad_fn=)
but if I use it in c++ code like

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    std::string _path = "C:\\Projects\\AnatomySegmTorch\\models\\vanila_rcnn.pt";
    torch::jit::script::Module module;
    //torch::NoGradGuard no_grad; //stops grad calculate
    try {
        module = torch::jit::load(_path);
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& ) {
        std::cerr << "error loading the model\n";
        return -1;
    }

   // Create a vector of inputs.
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(torch::ones({ 1, 3, 256, 256 }));

    // Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
    at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor(); 
    return 0;
}
```

It crashes on module = torch::jit::load(_path);
with C++: torch::jit::ErrorReport on address 0x0000006210DB8000.

I tried to convert the model to scripted and can't load it in c++ torch::jit::load
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hello, can you try tracing it instead of scripting it ? It should be something like `torch.jit.trace` I believe. Also what do the words in Cyrillic alphabet mean in your error message please ?

Comment: I've tried tracing but it looks like a bug in torchvision with this network. It wasn't successful.

Comment: I tryed to script resnet model from torchvision 0.14.0 - it loads in c++ well. I also made a wrapper for MaskRCNN: 
`class WrappedDETR(torch.nn.Module):    def __init__(self, model):         
         super().__init__()        
         self.model = model  def forward(self, inputs: Tensor) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor]:         
        losses, detections = self.model([inputs], None)
 return ( detections[0]["boxes"], detections[0]["labels"],             
            detections[0]["scores"], detections[0]["masks"])` but It has no effect. The model stilll doesn't load in c++

Comment: So just to understand correctly, you have managed to run other models (a torchvision resnet) and they work but this specific maskrcnn does not work, is that right ?

Comment: trialNerror, right

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of config problem.
Here is my approach to config:

1. Download Libtorch from [libtorch dl](https://pytorch.org/) and unzip it where you want.
   [image]
2. Add the lib folder to the environment variable

   Open My Computer –> Find This Computer on the left –> Right-click Properties –> Find Advanced System Settings on the left –> Find Environment Variables in the lower right corner –> Find path in the system variable box below, double-click Enter –> add the lib path in the libtorch folder, after adding it is as follows:
   [image]
3. Add libtorch to the qt project

   Create a file named torch.pri in the project directory and add these here(Note: change dirs with your unziped dir. Also list .lib file names in the lib directory.
   [image]
4. Add pri file to qt project
   Now add pri file to project by adding this line in the projects .pro file :
   inclide ('path_to_the_pri_file/torch.pri')
   .pro file would be like this:
   [image]

After executing qmake, the project has two more directories and each directory contains a pri file, indicating that the import is successful.

5. Set config to release

Because we download release version of libtorch, we have to use release mode on QT.
You can change it like below:

[image]

Comment: I build it with cmake. But The problem is not in some dependencies. The problen is that *.pt model doesn't load with module = torch::jit::load(_path); The program is builded. When I run the *.exe it stops on torch::jit::load without any messages...

Comment: Thanks. Does it crash?

Comment: Loading model via load command doesnt have any trick. you can enter fullpath of model file and check it. If its true your problem is that you doesnt config torch correctly. I dont use cmake. If you used my solution and have question, please ask. regards.